# Bedeutung von »so wahr mir Gott helfe«

Tags: meaning

Was bedeutet die Schwurformel »so wahr mir Gott helfe«?

Gilt der Eid dann nur, ***falls* Gott dem Eidleistenden hilft**? Falls ja, müsste Gott dem Eidleistenden dann nur zum Zeitpunkt des Schwurs helfen, nicht zu lügen? Oder müsste Gott dem Eidleistenden helfen, den Eid nicht zu brechen?

Oder gilt der Eid dann nur, ***weil* Gott dem Eidleistenden hilft**? Dies wäre dann das gleiche Konstrukt wie »so wahr ich hier stehe«, oder? Allerdings ergibt letzteres ja nur Sinn, weil es kontrollierbar/sichtbar ist, dass der Sprecher da steht – bei Hilfe durch Gott ist das ja nicht der Fall.

Oder gilt der Eid unabhängig von Gottes Hilfe, aber der Eidleistende ***schwört auf* Gottes Hilfe**? Der Eidleistende ist also bereit, fortan auf Gottes Hilfe zu verzichten, falls er den Eid bricht? Diese Bedeutung [gibt Heinrich Tischner in der *Sprachecke* an](http://www.heinrich-tischner.de/22-sp/9sp-ecke/artikel/201/2010/10-07-13.htm):

> Hier überschneiden sich zwei Gedanken: "Gott möge mir helfen" und "so wahr mir Gott hilft", das heißt: "Ich rufe Gott zum Zeugen an und setze seine Hilfe aufs Spiel, wenn ich meinen Eid nicht halte."

Comment: Inwiefern beantwortet der gelbe Kasten deine Frage *nicht*?

Comment: @tofro   Vielleicht gibt es eine bessere Erklärung als die zweier in einen Satz gewurschtelter Gedanken? Irgendwelche alten Verbformen vielleicht, die sich hier erhalten haben und uns einen Konjunktiv vorgaukeln, der eigentlich ursprünglich keiner war?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich sehe keinen Konjunktiv, sondern eine Art Imperativ in der dritten Person. Wenn der König nach Wein fragt, sagt er seinem Mundschenk "Schenke er mir ein!", also ein *Jussiv*. Konjunktiv ist das nur der Form nach.

Comment: @tofro   Ja, stimmt. Vielleicht habe ich zu lateinisch gedacht. An meinem eigentlichen Gedanken ändert das aber nichts: Vielleicht gibt es eine bessere Erklärung als die im rosa Kasten?

Comment: @tofro: Die beiden ersten Deutungen sind die, die ich für möglich gehalten habe; auf die dritte Deutung wäre ich gar nicht gekommen, habe die erst durch eine Websuche entdeckt. Allerdings weiß ich weder, ob man der Einschätzung trauen kann/soll, noch leuchtet es mir ein, wieso aus den beiden Gedanken ("Gott möge mir helfen" und "so wahr mir Gott hilft") folgen sollte, dass die Hilfe Gottes *aufs Spiel gesetzt* wird.

Comment: Für mich war es immer ein Beginn einer Bedrohung: Beispielsweise: *So Hilf mir, Gott,* wenn du jetzt nicht ins Bad gehst!

Answer (score 8):

Die grammatische Form ist die eines *Jussivs*, also eine Art Imperativ in der dritten Person, die im Deutschen formgleich mit dem Konjunktiv ist, aber außerhalb von solchen Redewendungen nicht mehr sehr gebräuchlich: Keiner geht mehr zum Friseur und sagt: "Er schneide mir die Haare". Mit einem wirklichen Konjunktiv hat diese Aufforderung wenig zu tun.

Der Schwörende ruft also Gott an, ihm zu helfen, den Eid nicht zu brechen.

Den Teil mit "so wahr" muss man, glaube ich, eher als "wahrhaftig", also "wirklich" verstehen. Bei einem Schwur geht es ja schließlich nicht um *Wahrheit*, sondern um *Wahrhaftigkeit*, weil man schwört, etwas wirklich werden zu lassen. Daraus ergibt sich "Ich schwöre bei der wirklichen Hilfe Gottes" - immerhin wurde diese Hilfe zu Zeiten, als die Schwurformel entstand, als absolut unzweifelhaft betrachtet.

Die Erklärung im Zitat ist meiner Meinung nach deswegen vollkommen in Ordnung und ziemlich treffend.

Comment: Nach deiner Erklärung leuchtet mir ein, dass Gott um Hilfe gebeten wird und dass dessen Hilfe (bzw. seine Existenz) mit dem "so wahr" als gegeben/real angesehen wird (richtig?). Aber enthält diese Schwurformel auch, dass der Eidleistende im Falle des Eidbruchs bereit ist, auf Gottes Hilfe zu verzichten (sozusagen als Strafe), so wie es das Zitat von Heinrich Tischner besagt? Oder ist es nur eine implizite Schlussfolgerung, da dies für Gläubige aus dem Eidbruch so oder so folgt (ob sie die Schwurformel nutzen oder nicht)?

Comment: @Beim Schwur "Ich schwöre bei meinem Leben" - Auf was ist der  Schwörende bereit, zu verzichten? - Natürlich, sonst ergibt der Schwur ja keinen Sinn.

Comment: @unor Und ja, natürlich, die Hilfe Gottes wird als gegeben angesehen (sofern man sich die nicht anderweitig "verspielt" hat). Man muß sich ins Gedächtnis rufen, wann diese Formel wohl entstanden ist (im "finsteren Mittelalter", also zur selben Zeit, als es einen deutschen männlichen Vornamen "Jochsamergott" gab, der so ziemlich genau dasselbe bedeuten könnte)

Comment: @unor Nein, meiner Meinung nach bedeutet es das nicht. Diese Formel dient der Bekräftigung des Eides (eine Art Eideshelfer), aber ein Brechen des Amtseides hat auf den benannten Eideshelfer keine Auswirkung.

Comment: Hier muss man, glaube ich, unterscheiden zwischen "heute" und "früher" (mehrere hundert Jahre zurück). Der Grad der Verdammnis bzw. das persönlich gesehene Risiko im Falle eines Wortbruchs ist mit der Zeit stark gesunken... (Das ist aber kein Aspekt, der die Sprache berührt)

Comment: @tofro "Der Schwörende ruft also Gott an, ihm zu helfen, den Eid nicht zu brechen." - In diesem Fall wäre die Formulierung aber nur bei einem die Zukunft betreffenden Schwur (etwas bestimmtes zu tun oder zu unterlassen) anwendbar, nicht aber beim Eid auf den Wahrheitsgehalt einer Aussage ("Hugo kann den Mord nicht begangen habe, ich schwöre, er war den ganzen Tag bei mir").

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Du lässt ausser acht, dass die Gerichte früher die Leute schwören liessen, die Wahrheit (und nichts als die Wahrheit) zu sagen, **bevor** sie ihre Aussage machten.

Answer (score 4):

Die Formel gibt es in praktisch allen [Sprachen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/so_wahr_mir_Gott_helfe). Ein interessanter Beitrag findet sich [hier](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291961/i-know-what-so-help-me-god-is-used-for-but-what-does-it-actually-mean), vgl. speziell Řídícís Antwort. Die *Herkunft* scheint nicht ganz klar zu sein, interessant ist aber eine [Publikation](https://lawpublications.barry.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1147&context=facultyscholarship) von Frederick B. Jonassen, die das hohe Alter belegt. Zitat (Seite 312 f):
[image]

"So wahr mir Gott helfe" bedeutet demnach nicht nur die Bitte um Gottes Unterstützung, sondern beinhaltet auch das Bewusstsein göttlicher Verdammnis bei Bruch des Eides.

Ich sehe hier eine Affinität zu dem bekannten Ausdruck "Dir werde ich helfen", der als [Drohung](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=%7E%7EIch+werde+dir+helfen%21+Dir+werde+ich+helfen%21&suchspalte%25255B%25255D) gemeint ist.

**Update.**

Bis heute leistet der Großmeister des Malteserordens seinen Amtseid mit der Schlussformel

> Cosi mi aiuti Iddio e se inadempiente sarà in pericolo l'anima mia.

Auf deutsch

> So wahr mir Gott helfe, wenn ich versage, wird meine Seele in Gefahr sein.