# "Respektiere jeder die Lage, in der er ist: so ist jedem gedient."

Tags: sentence-structure, pronoun

This post is on the sentence highlighted below.  The quote is from 'Brief eines Dichters an einen Herrn' by Robert Walser, which is the first 'Dichtung' in [*Kleine Dichtungen*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/37128/37128-h/37128-h.htm#Page_9).

> Wenn ich befürchte, daß ich Sie nur störe und keine Förderlichkeit und Erquicklichkeit für Sie bedeute, so ist die andere Befürchtung ebenso lebendig in mir, nämlich die (um ganz und gar offen zu reden), daß auch Sie mich stören und mir nicht erquicklich und erfreulich sein könnten. Es ist eine Seele in eines jeden Menschen Zustand; und Sie müssen unbedingt erfahren, und ich muß Ihnen das unbedingt mitteilen: ich schätze hoch, was ich bin, so karg und ärmlich es ist. Ich halte allen Neid für eine Dummheit. Der Neid ist eine Art Irrsinn. **Respektiere jeder die Lage, in der er ist: so ist jedem gedient.** Ich fürchte auch den Einfluß, den Sie auf mich ausüben könnten; das heißt: ich fürchte mich vor der überflüssigen innerlichen Arbeit, die getan werden müßte, mich Ihres Einflusses zu erwehren.

**QUESTION**

1. Is 'Respektiere' in the imperative?
2. What case is 'jeder' in (e.g. nominative, dative)?
3. How does 'jeder' contribute to the sentence?
4. What does the whole sentence mean?

**Background**

My guess is that the whole sentence means:

> Respect for each person the situation that he is in; that serves (suits, or is right for) everyone.

I try to understand 'Respektiere jeder die Lage' on the model of:

> Wasche dir die Hände!

But that would give me one of the following, to match the gender?

> Respektiere **jedem** die Lage, in der **er** ist

or

> Respektiere **jeder** die Lage, in der **sie** ist

Otherwise 'jeder' and 'er' refer to the same thing or person, and 'jeder' is in the nominative?  But in the nominative, what can 'jeder' be for the sentence (e.g. the subject)?

Comment: The meaning is approximately: "Might everybody be aware of his own situation; this will help everybody" - I tried to answer your question fully, but indeed there are some tricky and rare syntactical constructions in that sentence where I am not sure about the answer (e.g. is *jeder* a subject here, and if yes, what is the *es* that is left out but could also be present: *Es respektiere jeder die Lage...*) So let's wait for one of the grammar heros here.

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43117/bedeutung-von-so-wahr-mir-gott-helfe/43122#43122

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answers:

> Is 'Respektiere' in the imperative?

Yes, sort of, at least that is what it means. It is the *[Jussiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jussiv)*, a replacement form for imperative that uses Konjunktiv 1 as the verb form.

Jussiv is a bit archaic nowadays and not very often used, at least not in everyday conversation. Imagine the King asking his servant to serve wine, he would have said:

"*Schenke er* mir Wein ein"

Which is the same construct, or a typical excerpt from a cooking recipe that tend to start with

"*Man nehme* eine Flasche Wein und schütte sie in den Koch"

> What case is 'jeder' in (e.g. nominative, dative)?

Nominative. Pull it in front to see why: "Jeder respektiere...". Also see next answer why it needs to be.

> How does 'jeder' contribute to the sentence?

It is the subject of the sentence.

> What does the whole sentence mean?

While the jussive mode is typically expressed in English with something like "let's", for this specific example I would rather choose a form of "to be to":

*Everybody is to respect the situation he is in: This will help everyone.*

Comment: Wieder was gelernt, man lese und staune!

Comment: Bitte noch eine Auskunft: Wenn "jeder" das Subjekt ist, was ist dann "es"? - Denn der Satz kann ja auch heißen "Es respektiere jeder seine Lage...", nur dass das "es" im Beispielsatz der Eingangsfrage ausgelassen wurde. Ist "es" dann auch ein Subjekt? Hat der Satz zwei Subjekte?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Da ist kein "Es" im Beispiel, aber: Nein. Das "Es" ist in deinem Fall ganz einfach ein Pronomen, das das ins Nachfeld gerückte Subjekt "jeder" ankündigt und es (sic) hervorhebt - Genauso wie in "Es war einmal ein kleines Mädchen ...", bei dem auch das Mädchen das Subjekt ist.

Comment: Using third person singular to address someone is archaic, third person plural is not: "Schenken Sie mir Wein ein!" I think it can be argued that this is the same thing and not a real imperative either.

Comment: @CarstenS Third person plural (the "real third person") is even more archaic (at least with Konjunktiv). "Und so machten es zu allen Zeiten unzählige Seelen, welche Alles für Koth achteten, damit sie Iesum Christum gewännen" (Not a Jussiv here, bat rather an *Optativ*). And your example is a "real" imperative in my opinion.